# sidekiq getaddrinfo error(No address)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I'm trying to run sidekiq but I'm getting this error:

getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname

this is what I have in my sidekiq file (configinitializers):

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
config.redis = { url: 'redis://Policia9@host:6379'}
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
config.redis = { url: 'redis://Policia9@host:6379'}
end
```

Seems I simply used the non-existent host given in the docu, of course I need to put my own host or ip in there,but I don't know where to find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the `host` keyword with an hostname/ip address

this

```
'redis://Policia9@host:6379'
```

become

```
'redis://Policia9@12.12.12.12:6379'
```

assuming `12.12.12.12` is your host ip address

Comment: when i run redis i see 127.0.0.1:6379.Now, I did this redis://Policia9@127.0.0.1:6379 and when i run sidekiq  i get this error "NOAUTH Authentication required"